# iOS- Download 5mb size video from server using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, nsurlsession

I have a video on my server, I want to download that video into my app and play using `AVVideoPlayerViewController`. This is working fine. My question is, if the app has downloaded 1 MB video and the internet gone and if I start the app then the video is starting from 0 bytes. But I want to download the video from 1.1 MB like this. This video will download in foreground. Is this possible or I will have to use `backgroundtask` method.

Can anyone suggest me any tutorials or examples for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below links to download content using NSURLSession.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-2--mobile-21581

https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/

http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/